# Multi-pipe does not work

Tags: c, linux, pipe, ipc, pipeline

I need to implement such IPC-schema:

`runtime data -> filter1 -> filter2 -> output`. (same as `data | filter1 | filter2`).

I can pass data to first filter, but to second I can not (maybe because in first child stdout fd is not closed). How to properly implement such schema?

P.S. filter1 and filter2 just read from stdin and write to stdout.

My code:

```
int main() {
    int fd1[2];
    pipe(fd1);
    pid_t pid1;

    if ((pid1 = fork()) > 0) {
        char data[] = "Hello world!";

        close(fd1[0]);
        write(fd1[1], data, sizeof(data));
        close(fd1[1]);
        wait(NULL);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

    } else if (pid1 == 0) {
        int fd2[2];
        pipe(fd2);
        pid_t pid2;

        dup2(fd1[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        dup2(fd2[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(fd1[0]); close(fd1[1]);
        close(fd2[0]); close(fd2[1]);

        if ((pid2 = fork()) > 0) {
            execl("./upcase", "upcase", NULL);
            perror("execl");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        } else if (pid2 == 0) {
            close(fd1[0]); close(fd1[1]);

            dup2(fd2[0], STDIN_FILENO);
            close(fd2[0]); close(fd2[1]);

            execl("./reverse", "reverse", NULL);
            perror("execl");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        } else {
            perror("pid2");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

    } else {
        perror("pid1");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

}
```

Comment: "*maybe because in first child stdout fd is not closed*" -- It seems like you've already identified the problem. Since the first filter never sees EOF on its input pipe (since it's being held open by another process), it will never finish.

Comment: @Dolda2000 Yes, but how can I close stdout fd in outer process?

Comment: You have already closed it in the parent-most process; the problem rather appears to be that you don't close it in your `reverse` child.

Comment: @Dolda2000 "How can I close stdout fd in outer process?". I understand that fd is not closed. I don't understand how to close it before `exec`.

Comment: How can you not understand that when you're already closing all the other pipes properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are closing the pipes too early. Typically, you close `fd2[0]` before you use it in `dup2`. And as you redirect FILENO_STDOUT before the second fork, the second filter has no longer access to the original stdout.

Following code works:

```
int main() {
    int fd1[2];
    pipe(fd1);
    pid_t pid1;

    if ((pid1 = fork()) > 0) {
        char data[] = "Hello world!";

        close(fd1[0]); // OK, will no longer be used
        write(fd1[1], data, sizeof(data));
        close(fd1[1]);
        wait(NULL);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

    } else if (pid1 == 0) {
        int fd2[2];
        pipe(fd2);
        pid_t pid2;
        close(fd1[1]); // OK, no used from here

        if ((pid2 = fork()) > 0) {
        dup2(fd1[0], STDIN_FILENO);  // redirections for filter1
        dup2(fd2[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(fd1[0]);               // close everything except stdin and stdout
        close(fd2[0]); close(fd2[1]);
            execl("./upcase", "upcase", NULL);
            perror("execl upcase");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        } else if (pid2 == 0) {
            close(fd1[0]);             // not used here

            dup2(fd2[0], STDIN_FILENO); // redirection for filter2
            close(fd2[0]); close(fd2[1]); // close all what remains

            execl("./reverse", "reverse", NULL);
            perror("execl reverse");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        } else {
            ...
```